# Bring overlapping UIViewController to front

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, containment, uimodalpresentationstyle

I currently have three view controllers going on in my iPhone application at the same time. 
I use a [slidingView](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController/).

Here is my image:

[image]

When I tap on a table view cell, I want to open a new view controller like this:

[image]

(the egg is representing a new view controller.

But as you can see my orange view controller is in front.

How do I change this?

The code I use to open the `egg-viewcontroller`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIViewController *boxView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BoxView"];
    boxView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    boxView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    boxView.view.frame=CGRectMake(-50, 5, 300, 470);
    [self.view addSubview:boxView.view];
    //[self.view bringSubviewToFront:boxView];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be quite easy, you need your parent view controller (i.e. the orange controller ) to add the subview of your new view controller. You could normally do that by     `[self.parentViewController addSubview:boxView.view]` . But since you are using ECSlidingViewController , you could do it like this: 
`[self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view addSubview:boxView.view]`.

Of course then you will need to adjust your new ViewController's frame accordingly.

Comment: No problem Mark! To be able to close, what comes on my head now is you need to add a button/tap gesture to the view , and when you click/touch it, you gonna trigger [self.boxView.view removeFromSuperView]. I will suggest you declare your new view controller (i.e. boxView Controller) as a property , e.g. @property (strong,nonatomic)UIViewController *boxView, because u will want to access it like self.boxView